# In Ubuntu how can I execute multiple simultaneous terminals from PHP?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I have a script in PHP that I run from a CLI.

Inside the script I have the following loop:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

    exec("gnome-terminal -e php myscript.php $key $value > /dev/null");

}
```

What I am expecting to happen is that a new terminal will pop up and run my script and related arguments simultaneously in separate terminal windows.

Being able to visualize the data is simply for debugging. After I confirm that the script is working correctly, I want to run it in the background with this command:

```
exec("php myscript.php $key $value" > /dev/null &);
```

However, neither is working as expected. The second command, even though it runs, it still waits for the first script to finish before it goes to the next iteration of the loop.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. How can I get these to run simultaneously for debugging, and then simultaneously and silently in the background when not?

Comment: Since you're running another PHP process, have you considered using fork? http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: Try adding `&` to launch the gnome-terminal into the background.

Comment: @therefromhere I'm not familiar with pcntl_fork(). The php.net docs aren't very clear to me. Can you give an example on how to use it?

Comment: You may need to redirect all stdio for this to work if I recall correctly. I would try >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: This is a nice tutorial on pcntl_fork() http://fishtrap.co.uk/blog/2011/10/04/parallel-php-processes-with-pcntl_fork/

Comment: @DavidHoude I added that to both commands, and it had no effect. But I did fix the second script it by adding a second & after the 1 following Gerald's suggestion.  The script ended up being 'php myscript.php $key $value >/dev/null 2>&1 &' Why did this work and what do these > 2>& & mean? It had no effect on the first command, however.

Comment: The 1 represents stdout (normal output), and 2 represents stderr (error output), this redirects stderr to stdout, which is being sent to the file: /dev/null

Comment: @therefromhere After spending about 6 weeks really digging into forking and learning about processes, this was indeed the best route as I could never get my first direction to work without quirks. If you'd like to add that as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running another PHP process, have you considered using fork?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be: The webserver is running under a different user than you. It doesn't know where the X-Server is and the X-Server usually doesn't allow connectiosn from different users. So you have to do two things:

You have to make sure the DISPLAY variable is set when you run the gnome terminal from PHP. This should do it:

```
exec("DISPLAY=":0" gnome-terminal -e php myscript.php $key $value > /dev/null &");
```

You have to allow remote connections. You can do that with `xhost +` in a terminal running in your X-Session, but this will allow ALL connections, so be careful with it.

Comment: From what I understand of his question, the code executes the gnome-terminals fine, just not in parallel.

Comment: I read it that only the second command runs .. but not in parallel.